# how to read data from an input box and store in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a **JSON** object as follows:

```
var info = [
  {
    "place": "Turkey",
    "username": "jhon"
  },
  {
    "place": "Dubai",
    "username": "bruce"
  },
  {
    "place": "Italy",
    "username": "Wayne"
  }
];
```

And I have an **HTML** form that accepts the place and username as :

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="addJSON();">
      Place:<br>
   <input type="text" id="placeval" value="place">
   <br>
   username<br>
   <input type="text" id="usernameval" value="username">
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to have a `JavaScript` that will read the `values` from the two input boxes (`place` and `username`) and append them to the existing list `info` that is present in my `JSON`. Any suggestions on how to get along with it? Much appreciated!

Comment: That is not a [JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2):

```
function addJSON() {
    var username = document.getElementById('usernameval').value;
    var place = document.getElementById('placeval').value;
    var newObject = {
        "place": place,
        "username": username
    };
    info.push(newObject);
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpv7L8ks/

or if the fiddle does not work on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVrVEV
check the console to see the updated `info` here

Comment: where are the changes supposed to reflect? is it necessary for me to have the JSON in a different file for the changes to reflect? @k-nut

Comment: what do you mean? You would like to see the new `info` object?

Comment: you can just `console.log` it. Or would you like to see it somehow displayed in the html?

Comment: I want it to be updated in the file where I define my JSON. @k-nut

Comment: you cannot use javascript from the browser to write local files.

Comment: will the objects that I have added using your method stay in there? I could do with being assured of the fact that they wont get removed under any circumstances. @k-nut

Comment: what are the alternatives to using Javascript for the same? @k-nut

Comment: @TheLuminor come join me in the chat

Answer (score 1):

```
   var place = document.getElementById("placeval").value,
       username = document.getElementById("usernameval").value,
       infoLength = info.length;

       info[infolength] = {
                    "place": place ,
                     "username": username
        }
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and show it to me? I tried the same thing, IT doesn't seem to be working. @Kenny

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a simple javaScript. There is no need to use jQuery just do this.

Line 1 in addJSON() method creates an object and assign textbox values to the object properties. Line 2 pushes newly created object in an info array using push() method.

```
    var info = [{"place": "Turkey","username": "jhon"},{"place":"Dubai","username":"bruce"},{"place":"Italy","username":"Wayne"}];

    function addJSON(){
        object = { "place" : document.getElementById("placeval").value, "username" : document.getElementById("usernameval").value};
        info.push( object );
        console.log( info );
    }

</script>
```